# What does "this" keyword refer to in a class method?

Tags: javascript

I have read articles and documents about it and w3schools says:

> In a method, this refers to the owner object.

I have this method in a `class App` class:

```
_newWorkout(e) {
e.preventDefault();

const validInputs = (...inputs) =>
  inputs.every(inp => Number.isFinite(inp));

const allPositive = (...inputs) => inputs.every(inp => inp > 0);

// Get data from form
const type = inputType.value;
const distance = +inputDistance.value;
const duration = +inputDuration.value;
const { lat, lng } = this.#mapEvent.latlng;
let workout;

// If workout running, create running object
if (type === 'running') {
  const cadence = +inputCadence.value;
  if (
    !validInputs(distance, duration, cadence) ||
    !allPositive(distance, duration, cadence)
  )
    return alert('Inputs should be a positive number!');

  workout = new Running([lat, lng], distance, duration, cadence);
}
// if workout cycling, create cycling
if (type === 'cycling') {
  const elevation = +inputElevation.value;
  if (
    !validInputs(distance, duration, elevation) ||
    !allPositive(distance, duration)
  )
    return alert('Inputs should be a positive number!');

  workout = new Cycling([lat, lng], distance, duration, elevation);
}
// Add new object to the workout array
this.#workouts.push(workout);
// Render workout
this._renderWorkout(workout);
// Render workout on map as marker
this._renderWorkoutMarker(workout);
// Hide and clear form
this._hideForm();
// Set local storage to all workouts
this._setLocalStorage();
```

What i'm focusing on is the `this.x` part on the bottom. What does "this" keyword refer to in that code? When I console log "this" it gives me:

```
App#map: i#mapEvent: Object#workouts: Array(4)__proto__: Object
```

So it's the "app" class. Yet when i replace "this" keyword with "App" it doesn't work. And when i console log "App" it gives me a similar but different result. Which is this:

```
  class App {
  #map;
  #mapEvent;
  #workouts = [];

  constructor() {
    this._getPosition();
    this._getLocalStorage();
    form.addEventListener('submit', this._newWorkout.bind(this));
    inputType.a…
```

So, to repeat my question, what does "this" keyword actually refer to in a method? What am i missing?

Comment: `this` refers to the object, not the class. `App` refers to the class.

Comment: "*In a method, this refers to the owner object.*" - that's rubbish. Don't learn from w3schools.

Comment: I would recommend a different website to learn from.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: `this` in the method (or in any function, if that matters) refers to what ever object (or to null) it was bound when the method is called (excluding arrow functions). This is actually the only rule, but sometimes the actual function call is a bit hidden.

Comment: @Bergi "Hey! W3 Schools Teachers! Leave them kids alone!"